# not able to draw line using QGLWiget

Tags: qt, qglwidget

New to qt opengl. Am trying to draw a line in my opengl window it is not displaying. 
     Code is executing without error. Please help me. what is wrong in the below mentioned code.

```
  //glwidget.cpp
    #include "glwidget.h"
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QGLWidget>
    #include <QPainter>
    GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
        QGLWidget(parent)
    {
    }

    void GLWidget::initializeGL()/*initialize*/
    {
        qDebug()<<"iniialize";
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 102.0/255.0, 0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    }

    void GLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
    {
        qDebug()<<"resizeGL";
        glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)width, (GLint)height);
    }

    void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {
        qDebug()<<"paintGL";
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();

    }

    #ifndef GLWIDGET_H
    #define GLWIDGET_H

    #include <QWidget>
    #include <QGLWidget>
    #include <QPainter>

    class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

        void initializeGL();

        void resizeGL(int width, int height);

        void  paintGL();
};

    main.cpp
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

        QApplication a(argc, argv);

        MainWindow w;/*Mainwindow*/

        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you creating GLWidget?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should think about what you told OpengGL to do here:

With your

```
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
```

call, you set up your projection matrix to map the world in the area 0 to 1 (in X- and Y-direction) to your screen.

Then you draw a line from 0 to -1 (in X- and Y-direction). That line lies outside your screen now.

Try some better coordinates in your GL_LINES call.

Plus, you might want to start your paintGL() routine with clearing the screen:

```
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```